Configure Elasticsearch to suggest words or phrases based on partial matches in any position?
I am working on an Elasticsearch index where the name field contains sentences like the examples below:


Apple is my favorite fruit, especially when it's fresh and crispy.
The principle he explained was applied to solve the issue effectively.
She bit into the red apple juice, savoring its sweetness.
The scientist applied the formula to the experiment and found unexpected results.
After a long day, he enjoyed a green apple.


I need Elasticsearch to provide word or phrase suggestions based on partial input. The requirements are:

If the user types "ap", the suggestions should include:
apple
applied

If the user types "apple", the suggestion should include:
apple juice

If the user types "red app", the suggestion should include:
red apple


The suggestions should only provide the remaining part of the word or phrase starting from the matched part (e.g., typing "ap" should not just suggest "ap", but complete words like "apple" or "applied").
How i can do this with elastic search?

Can you please check this which i have asked long sometime back and had discussion in comment as well. It might help you to build your solution. Please let me know if you need any clarification after that.
